How to register Django hooks with PyInstaller
I want to use the Django hooks in Pyinstaller. I have tried the following:
        python -m PyInstaller
        --runtime-hook='hook-django.contrib.sessions.py'
        --runtime-hook='hook-django.core.cache.py'
        --runtime-hook='hook-django.core.management.py' 
        --runtime-hook='hook-django.db.backends.py' 
        --runtime-hook='hook-django.py' 
        --runtime-hook='hook-django.template.loaders.py' 
        ...
        --noconfirm 
        --console 
        --clean 
        manage.py

But I am getting
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.../hook-django.*.py'

Should I use the additional-hooks-dir parameter even with the built-in hooks, if so what value should I provide?

If I understand the error correctly:
You should write the path and not the import string.
Also in the documentation about runtime hooks a see this:

--runtime-hook RUNTIME_HOOKS
Path to a custom runtime hook file.

I'm referring to the documentation:
https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=--runtime-hook#cmdoption-runtime-hook
If you are sure that the 'import.string' should work - check if __init__.py file exists in the root folder of your project.

this is hook-django.core.management.py the file's name of the built-in hooks here https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tree/develop/PyInstaller/hooks.

pass, i see the names. But how it change the idea of my anwer? you need to write a Path to a custom runtime hook file, not only the file name.

I see, but it is not a custom one, it is package within the same installed Pyinstaller package

Eventually, I think adding this to the build command did the trick:
"--collect-all=django "
